# Ignoring 'A' and 'The' when sorting with XSLT

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to have a list sorted ignoring any initial definite/indefinite articles 'the' and 'a'. For instance:

- The Comedy of Errors
- Hamlet
- A Midsummer Night's Dream
- Twelfth Night
- The Winter's Tale

I think perhaps in XSLT 2.0 this could be achieved along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="play"/>
    <xsl:sort select="if (starts-with(title, 'A ')) then substring(title, 2) else
                      if (starts-with(title, 'The ')) then substring(title, 4) else title"/>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I want to use in-browser processing, so have to use XSLT 1.0. Is there any way to achieve this in XLST 1.0?

Comment: Usually the correct approach for this is to store a "sort title" for every element, since the rules can become very complex and even extend into other languages (for example "Die" is an article and should be ignored in the German language, but "Die Hard" shouldn't be sorted under "H", even if found in a German-language index). The sort title of "A Midsummer Night's Dream" would be "Midsummer Night's Dream, A".

Comment: I should have mentioned, starts-with() is available in XLST 1.0, but if-then-else is not...

Comment: @Joachim – you're right, but I need to work with existing data, there's no resource to maintain a parallel sort field; Gart's quick-n-dirty solution is just what I need – good comment, though

Comment: Good Question! (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:template match="plays">
 <p>Plays sorted by title: </p>
    <xsl:for-each select="play">
      <xsl:sort select=
      "concat(@title
               [not(starts-with(.,'A ') 
                  or 
                   starts-with(.,'The '))],
              substring-after(@title[starts-with(., 'The ')], 'The '),
              substring-after(@title[starts-with(., 'A ')], 'A ')
              )
     "/>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Plays sorted by title: </p>
<p>Barber</p>
<p>The Comedy of Errors</p>
<p>CTA &amp; Fred</p>
<p>Hamlet</p>
<p>A Midsummer Night's Dream</p>
<p>Twelfth Night</p>
<p>The Winter's Tale</p>
```

Comment: A second excellent solution, Dimitre, which avoids the maths of Gart's solution – thanks also! Since I had to think about it slightly more, I'll add for others' benefit: for 'The Winter's Tale', for example, the value it will sort on will be 'Winter's TaleThe Winter's Tale'.

Comment: @ChrisV: Yes, the advantage of this solution is that it is simpler and presents less chances for committing mistakes in doing arithmetics. Regardless that the sort keys seem strange, this doesn't affect the values that are finally output.

Comment: There may be issues if "The " is the middle of the text, more like "...Something The Something.." (sorry, can't think of any real example). Also, in general case the article "An " should also be treated accordingly.

Comment: @Gart: Certainly. But this question strictly says the articles are at the start of the play -- it's meaningless to eliminate any mid-word for the purpose of sorting.

Comment: One edge case I found with this is when the item to be sorted in in the form of "CTA &amp; Fred", the entry will sort based on the `&amp;`. This isn't a problem with "The ", but only with the easier to match "A ".

Comment: @JasonAller, Thank you for reporting this. See the fix in the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do that:

```
<xsl:template match="plays">
    <xsl:for-each select="play">
      <xsl:sort select="substring(title, 1 + 2*starts-with(title, 'A ') + 4*starts-with(title, 'The '))"/>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update**: *I forgot to add 1 to the expression (classic off-by-one error)*

Well, `starts-with` **is** from XSLT 1.0.  Prooflink: the first search result in [Google](http://www.google.ru/search?q=xslt+starts-with)  yields [XSLT 1.0: function starts-with](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_starts-with.html)

Comment: The problem is that `starts-with` is XSLT 2.0, I think - *Edit* I stand corrected!

Comment: I corrected myself as soon as i hit post 23 minutes ago, I just didn't want to remove the original comment because it seems suspicious to delete one's own mistakes.  Cheers.

Comment: Excellent simple, creative solution Gart – Thanks!