# sorting by first letter

Tags: xslt, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignoring 'A' and 'The' when sorting with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848641/ignoring-a-and-the-when-sorting-with-xslt)

I have a list of places, however some of theses places have the word 'the' in front. I need help in sorting these places in alphabetical order by discarding the 'the'. eg the mountains, should be just mountains. i can strip out the word 'the' to display the name by using substring however the sort doesn't seem to be able to read this.

I have this so far.

```
<xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="@places" />
```

example of what comes back:

alpha
sigma
the beta

would like it to come back with:

alpha
beta
sigma

this is just an example of how i stripped it from the name:

```
 <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring((@places), 0, 4) = 'The'">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring(
                                    (@places),
                                    4,
                                    string-length(@places)
                                 )" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="@places" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring(@places, 5 * starts-with(@places,'the ')" />
```

**Note**: You could also use `translate()` function for case-insensitivity.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, however it doesn't seem to work....i tried <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending" select="substring(@places, 5) * starts-with(@places, 'The ')" /> it still keeps it in the same order as if the 'The' was still there.translate will remove all the t,h,and e's from the rest of the name too. apologise...im not the best at this

Comment: i seem to have got it using <xsl:sort select="concat(substring-after(@places, 'The '), @places)" />...thanks for your help

Comment: @Hatzi: This `substring(@places, 5) * starts-with(@places, 'The ')` **is not what I wrote**. And the `substring-after()` solution is not quite correct: the substring could be in any place and not at first position.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yeah sorry, its not exactly as you had it....i ended up using substring(@places, 1 + 4 * starts-with(@places, 'The '))...thanks for your help

Comment: @Hatzi: Do note that adding 1 is not needed because starting position can be even negative.